# C - turn 3.00 into 3

Tags: c, integer

I've got multiple float numbers to print:

```
{3.00, 3.20, 2.23, 5.00, 3.40 }
```

They all have 2 decimal places, however if there are two zero's after a decimal, it needs to be displayed as a whole number.

How can I convert `3.00` into `3` and `5.00` into `5`? 
it is conversion not printing

Comment: Cast to an `int`. `(int) 3.00`

Comment: @Eli Sadoff I'm printing the numbers in a recursion. Numbers that are not 0 after a decimal should be printed as they are, but only those with .00 should be printed as a whole number. I don't know which numbers have .00 so I can cast them to an int.

Comment: @EliSadoff casting to `(int) x` is UB should `x`  has a FP value much outside the `int range.

Comment: What about a number like 1.996, it is not exactly 2, do you want to see `2.00` (to show it is rounded) or `2`?

Comment: @chux the number 1.996 will be cut into 1.99, which is what the output should be.

Comment: OK, how about `2.001` and `2.009`? Should print as `2` or `2.00` (to show the original number was not exactly 2) ?

Comment: @chux there is a restriction in the input itself, which takes exactly a 2 decimal number. And even if there are more than 2 decimal places, it will take only the first two. In `2.001`, it will cut it off into `2.00` which is gonna print only `2`.

Comment: Show us how you're printing the values.  You might be able to do something with `%g` instead of `%f`, but I'd have to take time out to read the [`printf()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/printf.html) manual page when I can just as easily allocate that task to you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to *directly* (i.e. using only the format specifier) print either two decimals or zero for a number ending in e.g. `3.20`.

You need to check if the number ends with `.00` *beforehand*; for example:

```
if((int)round(num * 100) % 100 == 0) // if decimals are `.00`
    printf("%.0f", num);
else // not `.00`
    printf("%.2f", num);
```

If `3.2` is okay for `3.20`, then the `%g` specifier might also be of some use.

Comment: There is no need for `int` math here which is UB for large `num` values.  Better for use `fmod()` or even `modf()` than `%`.

Answer (score 1):

Casting to integer type will truncate the positive integers down to integer part:

```
float f = 2.00;
printf("f: [%f], [%d]", f, (int) f);
```

> f: [2.000000], [2]

If you want to leave 2.50 as 2.5 then checking for .00 is necessary:

```
if( (int) round(num * 100) % 100 == 0) // if decimals are .00
    printf("%.0f", num); // truncate all
else // not .00
    printf("%.2f", num); // truncate to 2 decimal places
```

Comment: there is difference between printing and conversion.

Comment: The goal is to print them as truncated and casting to int achieves that.

Answer (score 0):

Just assign them to an int array or just type cast them in int for your purpose.

```
int i = 3.00;  //lhs is int and rhs is double i will store 3 only
(int)3.00   //cast
```

printing them with `%.f` will also work

Comment: your format specifier are right but they can't manipulate data

Comment: here there is no round off the decimal part will be truncated @George

Answer (score 0):

I think you cannot do this with a general format specifier or similar. You might need to treat each number separately and adjust the `printf` accordingly.

First you need to detect if you have digits that are 0.
You could do it like this

```
if (fabs(number - round(number)) < 0.01)
  printf("%.2f", number);
else
  printf("%d", (int) number);
```

This is just meant as a hint in the right direction. You might improve it a bit on your own.

Edit:
I assume that you want two digits for 3.20 and not 3.2 only.